# Is it possible to use unique_with on ReferenceFields?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I can't get `unique_with` working with `ReferenceFields` in MongoEngine. My model looks like this:

```
class WorkoutSchedule(database.Document):
    """ Defines a workout schedule """
    user = database.ReferenceField(User)
    title = database.StringField(
        required=True,
        min_length=3,
        max_length=30,
        unique_with=user)
```

And I want the documents to be unique if both the `user` and `title` are equal. However, this throws an exception:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    'ReferenceField' object is not iterable
```

Is is possible at all to use `unique_with` and `ReferenceFields` or do I have to solve this manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See documentation https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/defining-documents.html?highlight=unique_with#field-arguments:

```
unique_with (Default: None)
    A field name (or list of field names) that when taken together 
    with this field, will not have two documents in the collection
    with the same value.
```

So `unique_with` must be `basestring` or `list` of `basestring` of field names:

```
class WorkoutSchedule(database.Document):
    """ Defines a workout schedule """
    user = database.ReferenceField(User)
    title = database.StringField(
        required=True,
        min_length=3,
        max_length=30,
        unique_with=['user'])
```